# Modifying cventry in banking moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I would like to edit cventry in banking style to get something like this:

[image]
In fact I got something really similar, but I am having problems with the concept and to create tabulars. I would like that, if the Description parameter is bigger than one line, it still continues in the same "table", and that the Description and the Degree are all in the same line. Currently I have this:

[image]
Where, as you can see, the Description parameter has been manually tabulated with \qquad, and it is not in the same line or table

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\geometry{top=50pt}
\geometry{bottom=80pt}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}$\qquad\qquad\quad$\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{28}{30}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color0}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\@addressstreet,%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\hspace{1ex} \@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@mobile\hspace{1em}\textbackslash}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\hspace{1em} \phonesymbol\@phone}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emaillink{\@email}}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\hspace{1.5em}\httplink{\@homepage}}%

      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}
    \\
    \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
      \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
    \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace{1em}
  % optional quote
  \par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[94pt][0.4pt]{picture}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description very very very very very very very very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}            % change the symbol for lists

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}     % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                         % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For minimal changes to your code, use this:

```
\newlength\descriptionindent
\setlength\descriptionindent{\widthof{\qquad\qquad\quad}}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\hspace*{\descriptionindent}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\descriptionindent\relax}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Note what we've done:

- Created a new length for 'description indent'
- Changed the width of the minipage to be the line width less this indent
- Indented the minipage itself with this indent

I'd recommend tuning `\descriptionindent` to line up better.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this too:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.1\maincolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}
                                    p{\dimexpr0.9\maincolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}@{}}%
    {#2} & {\bfseries#3}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
     .\strut%
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr0.1\maincolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.9\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\geometry{top=50pt}
\geometry{bottom=80pt}

{\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{year-year:}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.1\maincolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}
                                    p{\dimexpr0.9\maincolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}@{}}%
    {#2} & {\bfseries#3}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
     .\strut%
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr0.1\maincolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.9\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{28}{30}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color0}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\@addressstreet,%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\hspace{1ex} \@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@mobile\hspace{1em}\textbackslash}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\hspace{1em} \phonesymbol\@phone}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emaillink{\@email}}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\hspace{1.5em}\httplink{\@homepage}}%

      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}
    \\
    \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
      \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
    \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace{1em}
  % optional quote
  \par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[94pt][0.4pt]{picture}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\the\hintscolumnwidth

\section{Education}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description very very very very very very very very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\section{Languages}

\end{document}
```